# What exercises can improve my squat depth? I'm limited by how far my knees go over my toes

Tags: squats, flexibility

I have trouble getting low in my attempts at "ass to grass" squats. I have realized my calves are to blame for lack of motion what should I do to improve their flexibility?

Comment: How is your form for squatting in general? Are your feet flat on the ground or do you tend to lean forward with the weight on the front of your feet?

Comment: See [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6589/1771) for a variety of good solutions. Often calf inflexibility is paired with ankle dorsiflexion immobility and both have to be fixed in order to have a solid squat.

Answer (score 2):

For me it sounds as if you are doing squats the wrong way. Your knees should *never* go over your toes, but rather be in line with your feet. Your shanks should stay in place - mostly. The saying is "ass to the grass" and this is what the movement is like, your behind is moved towards the floor *behind* your heels. Your weight should be on your heels *and* the balls of the feet.

For a more comprehensive discussion of how squats are done right, please see
http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2014/03/03/strength-training-101-how-to-squat-properly/