# Ankle stretching/mobility in preparation for return to Brazilian Jiu Jitsu

Tags: stretching, mobility, martial-arts

I used to be a regular practitioner of Brazilian Jiu Jitsu.  When I started out it took me a very long time to be able to sit on my heels for more than a few seconds.  It was uncomfortable on my ankles and also led to a lot of foot cramps.  Historically, it has been an issue in Yoga classes too (usually Vajrasana/Thunderbolt Pose), but it's not as central to a typical class as it is for the martial art class.

After years off, I'm thinking about making a return to the sport in the coming months.  I did a few experiments and I feel like I'm back at square one for ankle mobility after trying to sit on my heels a bit.

Aside from just sitting on my heels for increasing lengths of time, are there any exercises I can do to prepare my ankles?  It took months of class before I was comfortable when I first started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improve ankle dorsiflexion for full squat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32169/improve-ankle-dorsiflexion-for-full-squat)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov what I’m seeking, I guess, is plantar flexion exercises?  I need to be able to sit on my heels with my feet in plantar flexion for extended periods of time.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is even possible. I'm sure you mean dorsiflexion.

Comment: Dorsiflexion is moving toes toward the shin.  I'm talking about a position where the toes are pointing more toward the calf.  [Vajrasana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrasana_(yoga)) is the yoga pose, but we spend a lot of time on the mats in this position while watching instruction during a brazilian jiu jitsu class.

Comment: OH. You said sitting on your heels, so I thought you meant heels in contact with the floor.

Comment: That definitely explains both of our confusions :)